# Tabla model_has_permissions no se llena

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, permisos

Estoy trabajando con Laravel Permissions y dentro de mi UserSeeder tengo esto:

```
public function run()
{
    

    $roleAdministrador = Role::create(['name' => 'Administrador']);
    $roleEspecial = Role::create(['name' => 'Especial']);
    $roleSolicitante = Role::create(['name' => 'Solicitante']);
    $roleAlmacen = Role::create(['name' => 'Almacen']);

    Permission::create(['name' => 'dashboard.index'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleSolicitante, $roleAlmacen]);

    Permission::create(['name' => 'categoria.index'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleAlmacen]);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'categoria.create'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleAlmacen]);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'categoria.edit'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleAlmacen]); 
    Permission::create(['name' => 'categoria.destroy'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleAlmacen]);
    
    Permission::create(['name' => 'empleado.index'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial]);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'empleado.create'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial]);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'empleado.edit'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial]);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'empleado.destroy'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial]);

    Permission::create(['name' => 'despacho.destroy'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador, $roleEspecial, $roleAlmacen]);

    Permission::create(['name' => 'registro.index'])->syncRoles([$roleAdministrador]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name'=>'Administrador',
        'nomb_emp'=>'Administrador',
        'carg_emp'=>'Administrador',
        'email'=>'admin@admin.com',
        'depa_emp'=>'Sistemas',
        'empr_emp'=>'X',
        'estado'=>'ACTIVO',
        'password'=>'password',
    ]);

    $user->assignRole(['Administrador']);

}
```

}

Por alguna razón la table `model_has_permissions` no se me está llenando, pero el resto sí

[image: tabla]

Mi tabla `model_has_roles`:

[image: tabla]

¿Es que esa tabla no se llena de esa forma o no se llena en general? No encuentro información acerca de eso.

Comment: Quítale la ultima coma aqui `'password'=>'password',`

Comment: Ya, aún no se me llena la tabla

Comment: me parece que estas creando usuarios, no permisos ... puedes validar ...

Comment: no entiendo muy bien el comentario; ¿el error es que todo lo tengo dentro del UserSeeder?

Comment: No será porque los permisos de los asignas a un Role y no directamente a un User? Chequeaste que la librería no funciona?

Comment: O si no hay otra tabla, por ejemplo role_has_permissions o permission_role? Edit: revisando el código veo que es `role_has_permissions` https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/dbc6c18ef4b2d097350a5faf82382564748e6c97/database/migrations/create_permission_tables.php.stub#L100

Comment: ah, o sea que como el permiso se lo asigno a un role y no a un modelo la table `model_has_permissions` no se llenaría¿?

Comment: No sé exactamente cómo funciona internamente la librería, sólo le dí una mirada rápida. Pero tiene sentido para mí. ¿Se insertan en esa tabla los permisos que estabas buscando?

Comment: los permisos que sí se insertan están en `role_has_permissions `, entonces probablemente sí sea que como no se le asigna al modelo como tal, sino al rol, pues esa tabla no se usa